# List devices on USB Hub

Tags: lsusb

We have a client who have numerous USB modems plugged into 3 x USB Hubs, we need to confirm the details of these modems.

When listing devices via lsusb, it shows the 3 hubs, but not the devices plugged into them.

Is there a way to list them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally lsusb lists all devices whether they are directly connected on central unit or via a HUB. For example my mouse, keyboard and a USB key are connected on HUB provided by the screen.
If shows in a flat way:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0951:1642 Kingston Technology DT101 G2
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c050 Logitech, Inc. RX 250 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c316 Logitech, Inc. HID-Compliant Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then with a tree representation showing hubs:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

So it is strange that you don't see the modems if they are switched on.
Can you please send the output of commands `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lsusb -v` (which may be a bit long).
Commands are done with `sudo`, because if you are not user `root`, some informations may be missing.

Comment: Thanks ppoilbarbe, turns out the devices were not connected. This is at a remote site and we didn't have hands-on.